# How to turn on IE8 Compatibility View programmatically

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie8-browser-mode

I have some JQuery in a SharePoint webpart and it is not loading properly using the Quirks Mode with IE8.  It works fine with IE8 Compatibility mode.  it also works great using IE7 or IE8 Standard mode but that messes up the CSS on the custom master page we are using.  It works fine using Google Chrome and works fine using Out of the Box SharePoint Master Page.  So i thought i should turn on the compatibility mode of IE8 since that is the best way i could think of.  How can I turn on the IE8 Compatibility Mode using C# or JavaScript?

i tried using  tag and set it to IE=EmulateIE7 but that just turns it to quirks mode i want it also set to compatibility mode

Comment: Your HTML/CSS/JS needs to be fixed to be cross-browser compatible.  We can only help you do that if you post the relevant code.

Comment: Did you try meta x-ua-compatibility tag?

Comment: Try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Unless I have missed something, if you have control over the source then my emphasis would be on getting your script to actually work vs working around it by enabling compatability mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed a META tag that declares what rendering engine you want IE to use to render your page, but be sure to read the article to understand the scenario properly:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype

Better still, it's worth trying to fix your CSS issues rather than ask for a browser feature which may not be supported in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try and update your jquery version; many ie issues have been fixed recently